# No class Play in package play

Tags: java, playframework, compiler-errors

I have the set up

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
    <artifactId>play_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

in the project pom.xml. However, when I try to follow [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-java-websockets-advanced#deploy-the-code), the statement `play.Play.application()` does not compile, giving me output

```
cannot find symbol
symbol:   class Play
location: package play
```

Could anyone, please, help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the tutorial you're reading is using Play 2.0, which is rather old.

Lots of things have changed up to Play 2.7. Notably the removal of the global Play application in 2.6 (I think). In newer Play versions you need to inject the current application into your controller if you need that.

For your code at hand, you would probably need to inject the Redis component -- if that still exists for Play 2.7.

Better have a look at the new documentation here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Home